# How to continue using docker container after startup application exit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I want to create docker image that will start nano editor after running and give users possibilities continue work after nano closing.

For that I wrote next Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano
RUN mkdir /home/working
ENV EDITOR /bin/nano
WORKDIR /home/working
ENTRYPOINT /bin/nano
```

After running container *(docker run -it --rm test)* nano starts, but after exiting off nano, container closes. I want to continue work into ubuntu container after closing nano. What should i change in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wouldnt set the ENTRYPOINT to nano. better use /bin/bash.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano
RUN mkdir /home/working
ENV EDITOR /bin/nano
WORKDIR /home/working
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

now you can (if the container is running) access the container with

```
docker exec -it <containername> /bin/bash
```

and use nano as often as you want. for example to edit multiple files. after you close nano /bin/bash is still running and the container doesnt exits.